# Simple PHP GET question

Tags: php, get

> UPDATE:
>
> All the methods given below doesn't
>
> > work for:
> >
> > mysite.com?username=me&action=editpost
> >
> > but only for:
> >
> > mysite.com?action=editpost

---

I know how to detect if a particular GET method is in the url:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];

if ($username) {
   // whatever
}
```

But how can I detect something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com?username=me&action=editpost
```

How can I detect the "&action" above?

Comment: Uhh... `$_GET['action']`? (I'm not trying to be condescending; I barely know PHP myself.)

Comment: What you mean by saying "detect"? In your URL example you simply will have 2 parameters in `$_GET` and can always check both of them...

Comment: Why is this voted down? TMTOWTDI. We can discuss which one is the best.

Comment: Regarding your update: that's strange, they should work. Can you post the output of `var_dump($_GET)` when requesting `mysite.com/?username=me&action=editpost`?

Comment: *All the methods given below doesn't work for* : are you serious? Then something with your webserver is not correct or the URL has some evil, non visible characters.

Comment: @Felix: either that or `arg_separator.input` is messed up (unlikely).

Answer (score 2):

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($action) {
   // whatever
}
```

or

```
if(array_key_exists('action', $_GET)) {

}
```

Btw the method is called `GET`. What you mean are parameters.

Comment: Seconds... dammit. But you're a Felix, so it's okay. ;)

Comment: @middus: Ah, I remember. Greetings :-D

Answer (score 1):

All GET parameters are accessible in the same way.

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($username) {
   // whatever
}

if ($action == 'editpost') {
   // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_key_exists('action', $_GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_key_exists('action', $_GET) && $action = $_GET['action']) {
 // action exists
}
```

However, if an empty string (or anything that [evaluates to boolean false](https://www.php.net/boolean)) is a valid value, just use this instead:

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
 $action= $_GET['action'];
 // Do stuff with $action
}
```

Using `$_GET['action']` when action has not been set will generate a notice, depending on the error reporting level.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if(array_key_exists('action', $_GET)){ // returns a boolean
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way - $_GET is an array

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
```

Try `print_r( $_GET )` to see what's in it

Answer (score 0):

the parameters in the url are assigned to $_GET array from left to the right.

If you have something like

```
?username=me&action=editpost&somekey=somevalue&action=&someotherkey=someothervalue
```

then first 'editpost' will be assigned as action but then it will be replaces as '' and as a result

```
$_GET['action'] = ''; (instead of 'editpost')
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way as username:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
```